# Kafka replaces each negative byte on {-17, -65, -67}

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have a trouble with consume message from Apache Kafka topic.
As a producer I send the following byte array:

```
[-57, 114, 101, 115, 117, 108, 116, 32, 105, 100, 61, 34, 113, 79, 56, 85, 53, 57, 116, 75, 68, 112, 113...-107...]
```

But from Kafka topic I receive modified array:

```
[-17, -65, -67, 114, 101, 115, 117, 108, 116, 32, 105, 100, 61, 34, 113, 79, 56, 85, 53, 57, 116, 75, 68, 112, 113...-17, -65, -67...]
```

And every negative byte is replaced with {-17, -65, -67}.

Why such thing happens? Any help would be appreciated.